# how to make a web part visible to particular users in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I have created a webpart annual results.This should be available only to managers and not for developers in the home page.How to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MOSS then you can use audience targeting, but be aware that this should only be used as a way to help people notice what's important to them not as a mean of authorizing what they can see.

If you're using WSS then you'll have to write code in the webpart to achive the same functionallity

Answer (score 0):

Per Jakobsen is right, however that is still "security by obscurity".  If the data is being pulled from a SharePoint list then consider security that list or the list items within that list, your users who don't have rights will still see the web part but they won't see any data.